# Definition of spam

Tags: support, flags, spam

[Have a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606097/yesteday-i-watched-two-states-movie)

It's spam, right? Stupid, Pointless, <del>Amusing</del> Annoying?

So I went to flag it as spam. But...

> This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.

... No it isn't. So, by the definition of the flag description, is the question *not* spam?

Comment: I'd have flagged it for moderator attention: *please nuke pointless troll*.

Comment: Do we really want to take our moderators' precious time for something so trivial, though?

Comment: Yes, because this is a troll account. It should be locked or nuked. Which requires a moderator.

Comment: I would have flagged as VLQ

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, that makes sense. We users can only take action against the *question*, not the user. Gotcha.